# Excel Formula - Aggregate rows by ignoring duplicated values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, aggregate, countif

I have a table as below:

[image]

I want to populate the `Aggregate` column by doing a cumulative sum based on `ID` and `Code` column. Some of the rows have duplicated values, like row 2 and row 4, row 3 and row 5 etc. So that I can show that ID 1 has 2 unique codes, ID 2 has 3 unique codes etc.

I have tried this formula but it doesn't yield what I want.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,B2,$A$2:A2,A2)
```

My desired output is as below:

[image]

Comment: @SJR, That is the point, the OP does not want a 1 in row 3 and 2 in row 4 but wants the last image as the output.  The formula is not giving that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FILTER in Office 365, put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=@FILTER($C$1:C1,($A$1:A1=A2)*($B$1:B1=B2),MAXIFS($C$1:C1,$A$1:A1,A2)+1)
```

[image]

---

If one does not have Office 365:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:C1,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($C$1:C1)/(($A$1:A1=A2)*($B$1:B1=B2)),1)),IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,7,$C$1:C1/($A$1:A1=A2),1),0)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below formula-

```
=XMATCH(A2&B2,UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$12&$B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=A2)),0)
```

[image]